# Writing to a particular cell using csv module in python

Tags: python, csv

I have to write a value to a particular cell (say the 8th cell) in my csv file.
I can see there is a `csvwriter.writerow(row)` method to write an entire row, but I am not seeing anything to write a value to a particular cell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [**csv module**](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) provides facilities to read and write csv files but **does not allow the modification specific cells in-place**.

Even the `csvwriter.writerow(row)` method you highlight in your question does not allow you to identify and overwrite a specific row. Rather it writes the `row` parameter to the writer’s file object, in effect it simply appends a row the csv file associated with the writer.

Do not be dissuaded from using the [**csv module**](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) though, it is simple to use and with the primitives provided you could implement the higher level functionality you are looking for relatively easily.

For example take a look at the following csv file:

```
1,2,3,four,5
1,2,3,four,5
1,2,3,four,5
```

The word `four` is in column 3 (the fourth column but a row is just a list so the indexing is zero based), this can be easily updated to contain the digit `4` with the following program:

```
import csv
in_file = open("d:/in.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
out_file = open("d:/out.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
for row in reader:
    row[3] = 4
    writer.writerow(row)
in_file.close()    
out_file.close()
```

Resulting in the output:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Granted creating some generic function that allows specific rows and columns to be identified and updated is a little more work, but not much more as manipulating a csv file in Python is just manipulating a sequence of lists.

Answer (score 3):

suppose you have a csv file called mylist.csv with following lines:

```
a, b, c, d

e, f, g, h

i, j, k, l
```

if you want to modify 'h' to become 'X', can use this code, need to import csv module:

```
    f = open('mylist.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    mylist = list(reader)
    f.close()
    mylist[1][3] = 'X'
    my_new_list = open('mylist.csv', 'w', newline = '')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(my_new_list)
    csv_writer.writerows(mylist)
    my_new_list.close()
```

If you want to modify a particular column for each row, just add the for loop to iterate.

Comment: How would I use the for loop to iterate?
I'd like to add 3 characters to the same column on each row.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, this is annoying.  I wound up subclassing csv.DictReader.  This allows for cell based lookup edit in place, and dump.  I have the code posted on activestate:  [In place csv lookup, manipulation and export](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577996-ordered-csv-read-write-with-colum-based-lookup/?in=user-4177968)

```
import csv, collections, copy

"""
# CSV TEST FILE 'test.csv'

TBLID,DATETIME,VAL
C1,01:01:2011:00:01:23,5
C2,01:01:2012:00:01:23,8
C3,01:01:2013:00:01:23,4
C4,01:01:2011:01:01:23,9
C5,01:01:2011:02:01:23,1
C6,01:01:2011:03:01:23,5
C7,01:01:2011:00:01:23,6
C8,01:01:2011:00:21:23,8
C9,01:01:2011:12:01:23,1


#usage (saving this cose as CustomDictReader.py)

>>> import CustomDictReader
>>> import pprint
>>> test = CustomDictReader.CSVRW()
>>> success, thedict = test.createCsvDict('TBLID',',',None,'test.csv')
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(thedict))
{'C1': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C1'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '5')]),
 'C2': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C2'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2012:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '8')]),
 'C3': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C3'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2013:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '4')]),
 'C4': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C4'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:01:01:23'), ('VAL', '9')]),
 'C5': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C5'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:02:01:23'), ('VAL', '1')]),
 'C6': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C6'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:03:01:23'), ('VAL', '5')]),
 'C7': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C7'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '6')]),
 'C8': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C8'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:00:21:23'), ('VAL', '8')]),
 'C9': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C9'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:12:01:23'), ('VAL', '1')])}
>>> thedict.keys()
['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9']
>>> thedict['C2']['VAL'] = "BOB"
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(thedict))
{'C1': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C1'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '5')]),
 'C2': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C2'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2012:00:01:23'), ('VAL', 'BOB')]),
 'C3': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C3'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2013:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '4')]),
 'C4': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C4'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:01:01:23'), ('VAL', '9')]),
 'C5': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C5'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:02:01:23'), ('VAL', '1')]),
 'C6': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C6'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:03:01:23'), ('VAL', '5')]),
 'C7': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C7'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:00:01:23'), ('VAL', '6')]),
 'C8': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C8'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:00:21:23'), ('VAL', '8')]),
 'C9': OrderedDict([('TBLID', 'C9'), ('DATETIME', '01:01:2011:12:01:23'), ('VAL', '1')])}
>>> test.updateCsvDict(thedict)
>>> test.createCsv('wb')
"""

class CustomDictReader(csv.DictReader):
    """
        override the next() function and  use an
        ordered dict in order to preserve writing back
        into the file
    """

    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames = None, restkey = None, restval = None, dialect ="excel", *args, **kwds):
        csv.DictReader.__init__(self, f, fieldnames = None, restkey = None, restval = None, dialect = "excel", *args, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        if self.line_num == 0:
            # Used only for its side effect.
            self.fieldnames
        row = self.reader.next()
        self.line_num = self.reader.line_num

        # unlike the basic reader, we prefer not to return blanks,
        # because we will typically wind up with a dict full of None
        # values
        while row == []:
            row = self.reader.next()
        d = collections.OrderedDict(zip(self.fieldnames, row))

        lf = len(self.fieldnames)
        lr = len(row)
        if lf < lr:
            d[self.restkey] = row[lf:]
        elif lf > lr:
            for key in self.fieldnames[lr:]:
                d[key] = self.restval
        return d

class CSVRW(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_name = ""
        self.csv_delim = ""
        self.csv_dict  = collections.OrderedDict()

    def setCsvFileName(self, name):
        """
            @brief stores csv file name
            @param name- the file name
        """
        self.file_name = name

    def getCsvFileName(self):
        """
            @brief getter
            @return returns the file name
        """
        return self.file_name

    def getCsvDict(self):
        """
            @brief getter
            @return returns a deep copy of the csv as a dictionary
        """
        return copy.deepcopy(self.csv_dict)

    def clearCsvDict(self):
        """
            @brief resets the dictionary
        """
        self.csv_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

    def updateCsvDict(self, newCsvDict):
        """
            creates a deep copy of the dict passed in and
            sets it to the member one
        """
        self.csv_dict = copy.deepcopy(newCsvDict)

    def createCsvDict(self,dictKey, delim, handle = None, name = None, readMode = 'rb', **kwargs):
        """
            @brief create a dict from a csv file where:
                the top level keys are the first line in the dict, overrideable w/ **kwargs
                each row is a dict
                each row can be accessed by the value stored in the column associated w/ dictKey

                that is to say, if you want to index into your csv file based on the contents of the
                third column, pass the name of that col in as 'dictKey'

            @param dictKey  - row key whose value will act as an index
            @param delim    - csv file deliminator
            @param handle   - file handle (leave as None if you wish to pass in a file name)
            @param name     - file name   (leave as None if you wish to pass in a file handle)
            @param readMode - 'r' || 'rb'
            @param **kwargs - additional args allowed by the csv module
            @return bool    - SUCCESS|FAIL
        """
        self.csv_delim = delim
        try:
            if isinstance(handle, file):
                self.setCsvFileName(handle.name)
                reader = CustomDictReader(handle, delim, **kwargs)
            else:
                if None == name:
                    name = self.getCsvFileName()
                else:
                    self.setCsvFileName(name)
                reader = CustomDictReader(open(name, readMode), delim, **kwargs)
            for row in reader:
                self.csv_dict[row[dictKey]] = row
            return True, self.getCsvDict()
        except IOError:
            return False, 'Error opening file'

    def createCsv(self, writeMode, outFileName = None, delim = None):
        """
            @brief create a csv from self.csv_dict
            @param writeMode   - 'w' || 'wb'
            @param outFileName - file name || file handle
            @param delim       - csv deliminator
            @return none
        """
        if None == outFileName:
            outFileName = self.file_name
        if None == delim:
            delim = self.csv_delim
        with open(outFileName, writeMode) as fout:
            for key in self.csv_dict.values():
                fout.write(delim.join(key.keys()) + '\n')
                break
            for key in self.csv_dict.values():
                fout.write(delim.join(key.values()) + '\n')
```

Comment: after correcting that test.createCsv('wb') doesn't write any changes to the csv I loaded? Ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot `test.updateCsvDict(thedict)` ... I've fully updated the code and sample usage. Hope it helps. While the class doesn't have mutex protection, I kinda wrote it w/ the intent that it could lock around the getter/setter/writer ... so the createCsv function only writes out the class's copy of the csv, which is the virgin read, unless you call update first.

Comment: **Also make note that my implementation requires the lookup column to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Using xlwt module, one can perform multiple operations on spreadsheet.can write into particular or specific cell in Excel.

```
import xlwt 

from xlwt import Workbook
wb = Workbook() 
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1') 
sheet1.write(1, 0, 'stack') 
sheet1.write(0, 1, 'overflow') 
wb.save('stackoverflow.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to write a specific cell in a .csv file and you can't avoid using this module, there is a hard coding way to do it.

Let's say you want something in the cell H3:

```
with open("your_csv_file_name.csv","w",newline="") as openfile:
    your_csv_file_name = csv.writer(openfile)


    value_for_cell_h3 = "X"

    list_of_blank_columns_and_h3value = ["","","","","","","",value_for_cell_h3]   
    #Columns from A to G will be blank

    your_csv_file_name.writerow("")   #Row 1 will be blank
    your_csv_file_name.writerow("")   #Row 2 will be blank

    your_csv_file_name.writerow(list_of_blank_columns_and_h3value)
    #The "X" will be in the H3 cell
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be careful about making assumptions, especially when answering questions from years ago (this one is over twelve years old). In this case, your proposed solution would delete other cell values in the CSV, which is unlikely to be what the original question wanted. Some of the earlier answers here already show ways to write a value to one cell while preserving the existing values in other cells. Looking forward to your future contributions!