# Edit CSV cell using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to edit CSV cell value using pandas.

I'm trying like this

```
obj.set_value(rowindex, 'C', val)
```

Where I expect the old value in row = `rowindex` and column = `C` i.e.. `df[rowindex][C]` should get replced by `val` and my original csv should get update.

I know pandas provides, inplace=True, to do that, but set_value doesn't support that. How can I do this ?

Comment: I think the behavior of set_value() is inplace=True by default. Can you show us the error you are facing ?

Comment: @michaelg No error. It just doesn't update my original csv file. Just a warning `FutureWarning: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead`

Comment: The pandas data frame is not the same thing as the original csv file. Making changes in the data frame doesn't change the file unless you explicitly write those changes back.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That is what my questions is. How to do that? I tried with `inplace=True` that gives error while @michaelg says it is by default.

Comment: When you write CSV, you mean the original file of the dataframe ?

Comment: @michaelg yes..

Comment: I see, then you would use df.to_csv() to save back on your original file

Comment: I even tried `df.to_csv()` which was failing, catch was to use `df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the content of the original file `student.csv`:

```
StudentID,Name,Username,Password,Moderator
0001,Foo Bar,test,abc123,N
0002,Baz Qux,bob,bcd986,Y
```

### Load CSV

```
df = pd.read_csv('students.csv')
```

### Change the cell and save back to the original file

```
df.set_value(0,'Name','changed')
df.to_csv('students.csv', index=False)
```

### result

```
StudentID,Name,Username,Password,Moderator
1,changed,test,abc123,N
2,Baz Qux,bob,bcd986,Y
```

Comment: exactly, though it is working for most of the rows, can you tell why it is failing for some rows. This is the stack trace
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.csv'`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I am using python 3.6.

Comment: If you can show the exact code that produces your error, we may spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the data frame doesn't change the csv file since they are not the same thing. You have a few options.

1. Read the csv into a 2D list update the desired cell and the write the 2D list back to a csv file. [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699927/writing-to-a-particular-cell-using-csv-module-in-python)
2. Update the dataframe then use [df.to_csv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Try something like this:

```
df..set_value(rowindex, 'C', val)
df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```