# How to write to a specific cell I want in csv pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[image: csv layout]

if i want to write to B2 cell, how can i do it? can i use pandas or other thing?

Comment: please add your efforts and error that you are facing

Comment: Try looking at [Writing to a particular cell using csv module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3699927/16653700).